# Sync Google Calendar to Toggl?

Tags: google-calendar, integration, toggl

I'd like to sync the time of my Google Calendar events to Toggl using integrations (e.g.: using webhooks).

If some events are overlapping events, it should also not add twice the time entries, to not count time twice. I'd like this to start from now, without including past events of the calendar.

I'm sure there are ways to do this by tinkering with integrations and web hooks.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way I found is Zapier, it can react on finishing a Toggl activity and copy it to your Google calendar. It has some options and all, it's convenient but the free Zapier account only allows a certain number of actions per month so it's not really a long-term solution for heavy togglers.

Other automation systems can be found as well but I suspect they're also freemium style ones and work the same way.

Another way I discovered is using a Chrome plugin and start/stop events from there. Not the way of the samurai but I guess it will eliminate the restriction above.

Otherwise? I'm also looking for better ways right as we speak. I hate mediocre solutions.